# Where does WooCommerce validate coupons during payment?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a plugin that allows using coupons that are stored on a different system, accessed through a Web API. So far, I have used woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data to take care of applying coupon codes in My Bag page. However, if two persons applied the same coupon in this page and proceeded to place an order, both would use the same coupon (i.e. coupon used twice), because WooCommerce is not double checking with the API before placing an order.

In addition to the above problem:

- Which hook should I use to call the Web API and mark the coupon as used?
- How should I handle a communication failure at any stage?